# Exception in the allocation for the servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm fighting the whole day with this: I want to call the connect service method from `AuthentificationService` I have this exception (the rest of the code at the bottom):

```
06-May-2015 14:29:45.986 SEVERE [http-nio-8082-exec-28] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

06-May-2015 14:29:45.986 SEVERE [http-nio-8082-exec-28] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Exception lors de l'allocation pour la servlet net.iots.iotshub.web.service.AuthentificationService
 com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AuthentificationService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.iots.iotshub.web.service.AuthentificationService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AuthentificationService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/authentificationService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Servlet class:

```
@Path("authentificationService")
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AuthentificationService extends AbstractService {


    @GET
    @Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("connect")
    public User connect(@QueryParam("user") String id, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        JUser user = null;
        User connectedUser = null;
        try {
            user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(id, JUser.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new WebApplicationException();
        }
        ..................
        request.getSession().setAttribute("connectedUser", connectedUser);

        return connectedUser;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("disconnect")
    public void disconnect(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("connectedUser");
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        System.out.println(" LogOut ");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("isConnected")
    @Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public User isConnected(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        System.out.println(" isConnected ");
        if (session != null) {
            if (session.getAttribute("connectedUser") != null) {
                return (User) session.getAttribute("connectedUser");
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

my AngularJS service:

```
cmlAppModule.factory('AuthentificationService', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('rest/authentificationService/:path',
            {path: '@path'},
    {
        disconnect: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                path: "disconnect"
            }
        },
        isConnected: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                path: "isConnected"
            }
        },
        connect: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                path: "connect"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please if can anyone help me with this and provide the possible solution for it..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many things wrong on so many levels

1. There is no such word as "Authentification". It's "Authentication" :-)
2. `@ApplicationPath` should be used on the application configuration class, not on your resource classes. For example

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("/rest")
   public class AppConfig extends PackagesConfig {
       public AppConfig() {
           super("the.packages.to.scan.for.resources.and.provders");
       }
   }
   ```

   With this, you can get rid of our web.xml (or at least your attempted servlet configuration). This does pretty much the same thing. Change the package name to the package of your resources. And remove the `@ApplicationPath` from the resource class.
3. In your web.xml, you can't do

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>AuthentificationService</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
           net.iots.iotshub.web.service.AuthentificationService
       </servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   ```

   unless `AuthentificationService` is an actual Servlet (which I can't tell as I don't know what `AbstractService` is. In any case, even if it was, this configuration still wouldn't work.